# Uploading file in ASP.NET to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a website where users could apply to a certain job online.

A user must submit information in addition to a CV.

I'm new to this kind of work I would appreciate any kind of help.

Here is my attempt for the post method, but it generates the following exception:

> Unexpected end of stream. Is there an end boundary?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCV()
{
    IList<string> AllowedFileExtensions = new List<string> { ".txt", ".pdf" };

    var parser = new MultipartFormDataParser(await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
    IList<FilePart> files = parser.Files;
    IList<ParameterPart> formData = parser.Parameters;

    FilePart uploadedContent = files.First();
    var originalContentFileName =
       uploadedContent.FileName.Trim('\"');

    var originalExtension = Path.GetExtension(originalContentFileName);

    if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Contains(originalExtension))
        return BadRequest("Bad extension");

    string modifiedContentFileName =
        string.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        originalExtension);

    Stream input = uploadedContent.Data;

    string Url = string.Empty;
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    string directoryName = string.Empty;

    directoryName = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "Uploads");
    fileName = Path.Combine(directoryName, modifiedContentFileName);

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
        File.Delete(fileName);


    using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
    {
        try
        {
            input.CopyTo(file);
            file.Close();

            var cv = new CV{ Path = fileName };
            db.CVs.Add(cv);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(cv);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add your markup code.

Comment: There is no markup code, I test it via postman

Comment: On which line you get the error?

Comment: var parser = new MultipartFormDataParser(await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());

Comment: Can you try using .ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)

Comment: it says `cannot convert from 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<System.IO.Stream>' to 'System.IO.Stream'`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I should have chosen `form-data` in the body section, set the key with anything (e.g filename) and in the value choose file.
Also you need to create a folder in your path, in my case called **Uploads** in the directory specified.

Lots of thanks for those who helped.